# Why doesn't the contextual QRAC contradict Nayak's bound?

Tags: contextuality, randomaccesscode

A [QRAC](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/301250.301347) encodes $n$ bits in $m$ qubits so that one of the bits can be retrieved. Let $p>0.5$ be the success probability of the receiver correctly obtaining any one of the $n$ bits of their choice by performing the appropriate measurement.

[Nayak's bound](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9904093.pdf) states that such an $(n, m, p)$-QRAC must satisfy $m \geq (1−H(p))n$, where H(·) is the entropy function.
So for any constant $p$, the "compression ratio" ($m/n$) that can be obtained is at least $(1-H(p))$. That is we can only get a constant (in $n$) factor space savings.

[This paper](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2023-01-13-895/pdf/) introduces a Quantum Random Access code that claims (in section 7) to be able to store $\approx 0.5\cdot 3^u$ bits in $C u^2 1.5^u$ qubits where $C$ is a constant $\approx 243$, where the success probability is 0.999.

I'm confused how this doesn't violate Nayak's bound since the space savings is not a constant factor, yet the success probability is constant.